# AngularJS use $location but with refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was once used ui-router I remember there's something like `$state.go('/',{reload:true})`. In normal ngRoute how do I go to a page but refresh it? I don't see any option in `$location.`

Comment: $location changes the url which should do a refresh as part of the browsers default behaviour.

Comment: @George I mean a hard reload after the change. $location.path('somewhere') did not refresh, it simply go to somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
$route.reload();
```

$route.reload() will reinitialise the controllers but not the services. If you want to reset the whole state of your application you can use:

```
$window.location.reload();
```

Comment: where should I put it? after login I do $location.path('/home') then in homeCtrl I do $route.reload()? I tried that the page freezed.

Comment: $route,reload() refresh the current route.